# Extending a database by adding a table with new information, here is what I have, whats the issue?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have to extend a database by adding a table with information I will add later in the SQL, the exact question is: "You need to extend the movie database by creating a new table with the following schema: award", below is the SQL I came up with but doesn't seem to work, any help?

```
 CREATE TABLE Awards (
  Award varchar(50) NOTNULL,
  Year INT NOTNULL,
  Category varchar(50) NOTNULL,
  movie_id varchar(3),
  star_id varchar(3),
  FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES Awards(movie.movie_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (star_id) REFERENCES Awards(star.star_id)
);
```

If any info is missing to get help, let me know and I can provide it to make it easier, thanks!

Comment: `NOT NULL` is two words (but I did not downvote your question).

Comment: What does “doesn’t seem to work” mean? Does it error, if so what is the error message? If it executes but doesn’t create the table you’re expecting, what does it create?

Comment: It gives me a "near ".": syntax error" even after fixing the NOT NULL portion

Comment: If you’ve changed the SQL you’re running then please update the question with this new code. Also, include the full error message rather than just a piece of it

Answer (score 0):

The foreign keys should have the name of the foreign table before the parenthesus and the name of the foreign column inside the parenthesis. There shouldn't be a .

```
CREATE TABLE Awards (
  Award varchar(50) NOTNULL,
  Year INT NOTNULL,
  Category varchar(50) NOTNULL,
  movie_id varchar(3),
  star_id varchar(3),
  FOREIGN KEY (movie_id) REFERENCES movie(movie_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (star_id) REFERENCES star(star_id)
);
```